# Angular: How to route different modules on the same path depending on service

Tags: angular, module, routes

Imagine a service `ABService` with a method `isAResponsible: () => boolean` and two modules: `AModule` and `BModule`.

The question is: Is it possible to switch between `AModule` and `BModule` depending on what `isAResponsible` returns? And how do we 'reroute' and rerender if the value of `isAResponsible` changes? `ABService` may have several dependencies to other services so it would be preferable to make use of the DI system somehow.

Example:
If the route of interest is `/aorb` and `ABService.isAResponsible` returns `true`, than we would like to route `AModule`. If `ABService.isAResponsible` returns `false` however we want `BModule` to manage further routing. Note that everything should happen on a *shared* route.

I tried it with guards and `canActivate`/`canLoad` but didn't succeed:

#### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AorBActivateGuard } from './aorb-activate.guard';
import { ABService } from './ab.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'aorb',
        canActivate: [AorBActivateGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('./a/a.module').then((m) => m.AModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'aorb',
        loadChildren: () => import('./b/b.module').then((m) => m.BModule),
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [AorBActivateGuard, ABService],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### ab.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ABService {
  private aIsResponsible = true;

  constructor() {}

  switch() {
    this.aIsResponsible = !this.aIsResponsible;
  }

  isAResponsible() {
    return this.aIsResponsible;
  }
}
```

#### aorb-activate.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ABService } from './ab.service';

@Injectable()
export class AorBActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private abService: ABService) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.abService.isAResponsible();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can inject `ABService` in `AppModule` and listen for changes from `ABService`. Every time a change occurs we then can reconfigure (= switch modules) the router and let it navigate the same route. In this way we always have the responsible module loaded.

```
[...]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([], {
      initialNavigation: 'disabled',
    }),
  ],
  providers: [ABService, BooleanStorageService],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private router: Router, private abService: ABService) {
    abService.onABChange.subscribe(this.resetRouterConfig(true).bind(this));
    this.resetRouterConfig(false)();
    this.router.initialNavigation();
  }

  reloadCurrentRoute() {
    const currentUrl = this.router.url;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
    });
  }

  resetRouterConfig(refresh: boolean) {
    return () => {
      const constructedConfig = [
        {
          path: '',
          pathMatch: 'full',
          redirectTo: 'aorb',
        },
        {
          path: 'aorb',
          loadChildren: () => {
            if (this.abService.isAResponsible()) {
              return import('./a/a.module').then((m) => m.AModule);
            } else {
              return import('./b/b.module').then((m) => m.BModule);
            }
          },
        },
      ];

      this.router.resetConfig(constructedConfig);

      if (refresh) this.reloadCurrentRoute();
    };
  }
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-szsydq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Answer (score 1):

You can you try this instead, I have just checked locally it works, just think it in a different way and you have your solution :)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AorBActivateGuard } from './aorb-activate.guard';
import { ABService } from './ab.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'aorb',
        loadChildren: () => {
          if ((new ABService()).isAResponsible()){
            return import('./a/a.module').then((m) => m.AModule)
          } else {
            return import('./b/b.module').then((m) => m.BModule)
          }
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [AorBActivateGuard, ABService],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think my scenario in the question was a bit oversimplified since `ABService` may have several dependencies we don't want to manage. I have updated the question asking for DI. Maybe we can tweak this solution to make Angular inject `ABService`?  I only know DI on the class level.

Comment: Your service is also a class, you can easily create an instance of it and then call its specific methods, may be you can check how angular create an instance of any service and use a same mechanism in the ngmodule? No sure but this is just a thought